# Struggling with doubly linked list methods

Tags: c#, pointers, methods, nodes, doubly-linked-list

Apologies I am new to this, I have to populate this list for some coursework and whenever I run the program my TraverseForward method is printing the list backwards and TraverseBackward is only printing one name 'Ardhendu'.

Edit: I seem to have solved a few of the problems now I just can't figure out to call the delete function on my fourth element 'Peter' UPDATED CODE BELOW:

```
class MyDoublyLinkedList
    {
        private string name;
        public MyDoublyLinkedList next;
        public MyDoublyLinkedList prev;
        private MyDoublyLinkedList head;

        //Default Constructor
        public MyDoublyLinkedList()
        {
            name = "";
            next = null;
            prev = null;
        }
        //Constructor with parameter
        public MyDoublyLinkedList(string value)
        {
            name = value;
            next = null;
            prev = null;
        }

        //Assign head pointer to the first node
        public void AssignHead()
        {
            head = this;
        }

        //Insert a new node with a value AFTER the current node
        public void InsertNextNode(MyDoublyLinkedList current, string value)
        {
            MyDoublyLinkedList node = new MyDoublyLinkedList(value);
            if (current.next == null)
            {
                //Insert at the end and easy to handle

                node.next = null;
                node.prev = current;
                current.next = node;
              
            }
            else
            {
                //Insert in the middle               
                //Look lecture slides for the pseudocode for adding node in the middle

                MyDoublyLinkedList temp = current.next;
                current.next = node;
                temp.prev = node;
                node.next = temp;
                node.prev = current;
            }
            
        }

        //Insert a new node with a value BEFORE the current node
        public void InsertPrevtNode(MyDoublyLinkedList current, string value)
        {
            MyDoublyLinkedList node = new MyDoublyLinkedList(value);
            if (current.prev == null)
            {
                //Insert in the begining 
              
                node.prev = null;
                node.next = current;
                current.prev = node;
                
                //Add the rest of your code here....
                //Look lecture slides for the pseudocode for adding node in the begining
               
            }
            
            else
            {
                //Insert in the middle               
                //Look lecture slides for the pseudocode for adding node in the middle

                //Add your code here
                MyDoublyLinkedList temp = current.prev;
                node.prev = temp;
                node.next = current;
                current.prev = node;
                temp.next = node;
              
               

            }
            node.next.prev = node;
        }
        public void DeleteNode()
        {
            //Check for ERROR if you are deleting a node which is referred by many pointers.
            //Update all these pointers before deleting (releasing) memory!
            
            if (next == null)//last node
            {
                //Delete the last node
                //Look lecture slides for the pseudocode for deleting last node 
                MyDoublyLinkedList temp = head;
                head = head.prev;
                temp = null;
                head.next = null;
            }
            else if (prev == null)
            {
                //Delete head node
                //Look lecture slides for the pseudocode for deleting head node 
                MyDoublyLinkedList temp = head;
                head = head.next;
                temp = null;
                head.prev = null;
                
               
            }
            else
            {
                //Update the next node pointer and reset the deleted node to null
                //Look lecture slides for the pseudocode for deleting a node in the middle

                //Add your code here
                next.prev = prev;
                prev.next = next;


            }
        }

        //Traverse forward
        public void TraverseForward(MyDoublyLinkedList node)
        {
            //Print the values stored in each node from current to tail
           // MyDoublyLinkedList last = null;
            Console.WriteLine("Traversing in forward direction...");
            while (node != null)//Traverse from the current node
            {
                //Add your code here

                Console.WriteLine(node.name);
               // last = node;
                node = node.next;
            }
        }

        //Traverse Backward
        public void TraverseBackward(MyDoublyLinkedList node)
        {
            //Print the values stored in each node from current to head
            Console.WriteLine("Traversing in backward direction...");
            while (node != null)//Traverse from the current node
            {
                //Add your code here
                
                Console.WriteLine(node.name);
                node = node.prev;

            }
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create the first node
            MyDoublyLinkedList node = new MyDoublyLinkedList("Ardhendu");

            //Assign head
            node.AssignHead();
            //Add 9 more consecutive nodes (Tom, Jones, David, Andrew, Peter, Mark, Collette, Dave, Dan)
            for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                //Add your code here

                node.InsertNextNode(node, "Tom");
              

                node.InsertNextNode(node, "Jones");
                

                node.InsertNextNode(node, "David");
                

                node.InsertNextNode(node, "Andrew");
               

                node.InsertNextNode(node, "Peter");
               
                node.InsertNextNode(node, "Mark");
               

                node.InsertNextNode(node, "Collette");
                

                node.InsertNextNode(node, "Dave");
                

                node.InsertNextNode(node, "Dan");
                break;

            }
            //Traverse the linked list from head to tail
            
            //Add your code here
            node.TraverseForward(node);

            //Delete Peter node and then traverse forward

            //Add your code here
            MyDoublyLinkedList temp = node;
            temp = node;


            for (int k = 0; k < 1; k++)
            {
                node.DeleteNode();
                node.TraverseForward(node);
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }


            //Insert Peter after Mark and then traverse backward

            //Add your code here
            node.TraverseBackward(node.next);

        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could assist in guiding me towards how to call the delete function on a node i.e. node.DeleteNode(); and why my TraverseBackward function is only printing one name that would be absolutely fabulous!
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFFEA.png)

Comment: IMHO You should have 2 classes, one for the list & head (and perhaps tail) reference. One for the list element, next & prev references.

Comment: The assignment was just given to complete the skeleton code, I would like to make further use after with other class calls though if that's what you mean?

Comment: You are creating a list of objects, with links forwards and backwards. What would a head reference mean on each node? That head variable does not belong inside your list node class. Your main method starts by assigning `node` to a single list element. Is this node variable always going to be the first element in the list? How would you change it? I can't help you tweak the rest of your code, to make it work, while it contains such a fundamental problem.

Comment: Fun exercise... A couple of hints: **1)** After you _"add 9 more consecutive nodes"_... The order of the list will be `Ardhendu, Dan, Dave, ..., Tom` because each one (after `Tom`) will _"Insert in the middle"_. And **2)** in `InsertPrevtNode(...)`, `current.prev.next == current`.

Comment: @rfmodulator you mean change  if (current.prev == null) to current.prev.next == current? apologies the if statements and for loop at the end were wrote by my tutor so I'm trying to interpret his code too. Thanks for your time!

Comment: No, I'm just saying the next node after the previous node is the current node, by definition. In your original post (before the edit), you referenced `current.prev.next` twice. I'm not going to get too deep into this... like I said, fun exercise! If I were you I would focus on implementing the linked list first, then double it.

Comment: @rfmodulator thanks again buddy I've updated the code and most of it is working now I believe, one or two obstacles left and I can erase this from memory :'D